# Python: How to determine how much same elements in a list are after each other?

Tags: python, list, ord

For our lecture, we need to create a program. 
Now we are at a point where we need help.

Let´s assume we have this following list:

```
[['W'], ['B'], ['B'], ['W'], ['B'], ['B'], ['B']]
```

Now, every letter  ('W', 'B') has a specific value 
Just when there are two letters after each other, a player will get the points. 
Example:

In the list above, player 'W' would not get any point, but Player 'B' would get 5 points. 2 Points since the second element and the third element are after each other, and 3 points since the fifth, the sixth and the seventh element are after each other.

I hope it is clear what i am talking about :)

So, how do i determine, how much elements after each other are of the same value?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Homework is meant for you to solve... unless you're willing to share the A+ you get when you turn in our solution ;)

Comment: the homework is the whole game. We are now stucking at this little point. I am not asking to create the whole game ;)

Comment: In the current state, we are searching for an appropriate built-in function. We know how to determine the amount of the values with collections.counter, but it does not help us to determine the length if an list is interruptet, e.G. 3 Times a 'B' and then a 'W'. Moreover, our teacher told us to use for this part of the work less than 25 lines

Comment: why are the characters wrapped in single element lists?

Comment: In the first place, we created a game-board, of the range 7x7. The user is allowed to set a specific stone in one of this fields. By using __getitem__ we receive this kind of format.

Comment: In less than 25 lines you can brute force this in a for loop to two dictionaries with score counters. Is this something you do not want to do and expect something more "pythonic"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to iterate "groups" of equal elements in a list. Just determine the length of those groups and increase the scores accordingly:

```
lst = ['W', 'B', 'B', 'W', 'B', 'B', 'B']
scores = {c: 0 for c in set(lst)}
for k, g in itertools.groupby(lst):
    n = len(list(g))
    if n > 1:
        scores[k] += n
```

(Note: The solution is intentionally incomplete and using a slightly different input.)

Update: Assignment seems to be over; added full code.

Comment: Hmn, we tried it - i don´t get how this should work.

Comment: @Jim.Hoti Well, I tried it, too, and it works. This will group the list into groups of `[[W], [B, B], [W], [B, B, B]]`, then just check the elements per group.

Comment: Okay, but what do you mean with scores[k] -> scores value is not defined?

Comment: @Jim.Hoti Yes, that's what I meant with "intentionally incomplete". Can you think of a built-in data structure that could be used for that?

Comment: I could by searching in the library, but we were discussing until now what effect this should have.

Comment: if lst[[k] != lst[k+1]: this could be the if-condition, or? This would mean that if the k-element of the list is not the same as the k+1-element of the list, these elements should be cutted and appended to another list. Is this thought correctly?

Comment: @Jim.Hoti Nope. I suggest you read the documentation to `groupby` I linked to in the answer in order to understand what `k` and `g` (and thus `n`) refer to. Then it will become clear to you.

Comment: @Jim.Hoti What effect it should have? Well, the effect you asked for in your question. And you don't have to search any libraries, it's a builtin. Spoilers: It starts with a `d` and ends in `ict`.

Comment: Dead tobias_k, we are trying very hard and we have so much more to do until tomorrow. Can you please tell us the solution?

Comment: @Jim.Hoti Try `scores = {'W': 0, 'B': 0}` (a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict) mapping player names to their scores) and the `if` check has something to do with `n`. And BTW, last time I checked I still had a pulse.

Comment: sorry, i meant 'Dear'. Thank you very much for your engagement. We found a different solution. We specified different for-loops with different ranges and checked whether the first element is same as the third element and so on.